# SequelizeJS : How to mandate null values in result?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a [sequelize.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) model with the following attributes

```
ratings: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    required: true
},
comments: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    required: false
}
```

When I query the model, attributes with null values seems to be omitted in the result. For example, if my comment is null, I get this in my result.

```
{
     ratings : 5
}
```

I want

```
{
     ratings : 5,
     comment : null
}
```

How do I achieve this without manually inserting `comment:null` in my result?

Comment: What query are you executing?

Comment: Did you try `allowNull: true` in your model definition?